# Como abrir, ler o arquivo e salvar em uma lista de listas o conteúdo do arquivo usando Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu tenho uma lista com caminhos de *arquivos.txt*

Com a função read(), posso salvar o conteúdo inteiro do arquivo dentro de uma lista em que cada palavra é guardada em uma posição da lista.
Porém como eu pretendo ler 3 arquivos de uma vez e salvar o conteúdo de cada arquivo em uma lista, pensei em salvar essas 3 listas geradas dos respectivos 3 arquivos em uma lista de listas. Seria algo mais ou menos assim que estou tentando rascunhar:

```
lista_nome_base_docs = ['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt']
tamanho_lista_base_docs = len(lista_nome_base_docs)
print (tamanho_lista_base_docs)

lista_string_arquivos = [[]]

for i in range(3):
    with open(lista_nome_base_docs[i],"r") as arquivo:
    lista_string_arquivos.append(arquivo.read())

print (lista_string_arquivos)
```

Estou tentando salvar o conteúdo de cada arquivo em uma lista de listas... alguém saberia me dar um ideia de como poder resolver isto?

no final quando mando printar, está saindo totalmente estranho está lista de listas:

```
[[], '€\x03]q\x00]q\x01a.', '€\x03]q\x00]q\x01a.', '€\x03]q\x00]q\x01a.']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente, você pode abrir os 3 arquivos simultaneamente usando o `with` , dessa forma:

```
with open('a.txt') as a, open('b.txt') as b, open('c.txt') as c:
    #faca_algo_aqui
```

Depois, pode usar o método `.readlines()` para retornar uma lista de cada arquivo separando cada linha em um item de lista.

```
conteudo_a = a.readlines()
conteudo_b = b.readlines()
conteudo_c = c.readlines()
```

E após isso juntar todas elas em uma lista geral:

```
conteudo_geral = []
for conteudo in [conteudo_a,conteudo_b,conteudo_c]:
    conteudo_geral.append(conteudo)
```

E por fim seu script ficaria assim:

```
lista_geral = []

with open('a.txt') as a, open('b.txt') as b, open('c.txt') as c:
    conteudo_a = a.readlines()
    conteudo_b = b.readlines()
    conteudo_c = c.readlines()

    for conteudo in [conteudo_a, conteudo_b, conteudo_c]:
        lista_geral.append(conteudo)
```

Comment: legal mano...  porém eu pensei do _for_ porque a ideia é do arquivo de **entrada.txt** ter uma base de outro arquivos, um em cada linha, então verificaria quantas linhas possui a **entrada** e faria um loop para percorrer, pois a quantidade de arquivos dentro do **entrada** pode variar... sacou o que quis dizer?

Comment: consegui mano fazendo desta forma: `tamanho = len(lista_nome_base_docs)
print (tamanho)

lista_geral_arquivos = []


for i in range(tamanho):
    with open(lista_nome_base_docs[i],"r") as arquivo:
        conteudo = arquivo.readlines()
        lista_geral_arquivos.append(conteudo)

print (lista_geral_arquivos)`

Comment: Ahh entendi. É que você falou sobre ler os arquivos de uma vez, por isso fiz o código seguindo essa recomendação, e o with passando os 3 de uma vez resolveria.. Mas como queria ler um e usar como entrada de outro o código seria outro. Mas que bom que resolveu.